# Remote connection to Tabular Services

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssas, ssas-tabular

I can connect remotely to Database Engine using MS, but not to SSAS Tabular. Server is in Azure.

Connection to Tabular instance on local server works, with same user (My user is server administrator on SSAS). When I am trying from different server, I get:

```
TITLE: Connect to Server
------------------------------

Cannot connect to Tabular.

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

A connection cannot be made. Ensure that the server is running. (Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AppLocal.AdomdClient)

------------------------------

A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond xxxx:2383 (System)
```

I am using SSAS 13.0.4001.0 version 1200 compatibility level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow the steps outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42171234/5070440) assuming you have a named instance for Tabular rather than the default instance.